# Display unique values based on status

Tags: sql, join, teradata

Table 1

```
vendor  SID STATUS  
1234    100 I   
567     200 NULL
```

Table 2

```
vendor  SID STATUS  address
1234    100 I       Stallionln
1234    100 NULL    Antlerln
567     200 NULL    prairee
```

RESULT

```
Table1.vendor   Table1.SID  Table2.address
1234            100         Stallionln
567             200         prairee
```

Kindly provide inputs to resolve the `address` ,basically `Table2` can have two status's `I` and `null` or just `NULL`. If a `vendor` has 2 status's in `Table2` query should display only the address from status `I`, if there is no `I` record display `address` pertaining to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join in `table2` twice. Once for `status = 'I'` and a second time for `status IS NULL` then coalesce the results:

```
SELECT
    t1.vendor,
    t1.SID,
    COALESCE(t2I.address, t2Null.address) as address
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2I 
        ON  t1.vendor = t2I.vendor
            AND t2I.status = 'I'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2Null
        ON  t1.vendor = t2Null.vendor
            AND t2Null.status IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER to get only one address per vendor:

```
SELECT
    t1.vendor,
    t1.SID,
    t2.address
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
 ( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM table2
   QUALIFY
      ROW_NUMBER() -- return only one row per vendor, prefer status 'I'
      OVER (PARTITION BY vendor
            ORDER BY status NULLS LAST) = 1
 ) AS t2 
ON t1.vendor = t2I.vendor
```